# Calling a Fortran function from Qt C++

Tags: c++, qt, fortran

I have this Fortran code.

```
subroutine DLL_TEST_PROJECT_001(dielconst, tandelta, kappa)
! Expose subroutine DLL_TEST_PROJECT_001 to users of this DLL
!
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT::DLL_TEST_PROJECT_001
! Variables
implicit none
real*8::dielconst
real*8::tandelta
complex*16::kappa
! Body of DLL_TEST_PROJECT_001
kappa = dielconst * dcmplx(1.d0, tandelta)
end subroutine DLL_TEST_PROJECT_001
```

The return value is a complex (complex in C++).

Here's the C++ code.

```
typedef complex<double> (*forTest)(double, double);
library.load("C:\\forTest");
// The library loads ok.
forTest ft = (forTest)library.resolve("DLL_TEST_PROJECT_001");
// The function resolves ok and we have an address in ft.
// Now if I call the function...
complex<double> d = ft(1.0, 1.0);
// or just...
ft(1.0, 1.0);
// The app crashes with a segmentation fault.
```

I'm guessing that the crash has something to do with the return value of the Fortran function.

Any help?

Comment: I would suggest using [tag:fortran-iso-c-binding]

Comment: I don't have access to the Fortran compiler.

Comment: This can either be a calling convention problem, or as you guess, the return value. You should post the `complex` template you are using and possibly the corresponding fortran code. A possible solution can be aligning the structure to match that of the one the Fortran code uses. Both information should be possible to know for sure if you know how the Fortran code was compiled (which compiler, which settings etc.)

Comment: Vladimir, you're right on. That worked. I don't know Fortran and I was tossed into the deep end here. I guess I thought that it would return an value (Like C does). I would have reached this with trial and error eventually but you got me there quicker. Thanks!

Comment: If you need to return a value as a function then use a Fortran function, not a subroutine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fortran subroutine

```
subroutine DLL_TEST_PROJECT_001(dielconst, tandelta, kappa)
  real*8 :: dielconst
  real*8 :: tandelta
  complex*16 :: kappa
```

is equivalent to the C++ void function

```
void c_name(double *dielconst, double *tandelta, complex <double> *kappa)
```

(provided `double` is equivalent to `real*8`, which is common)

The wrong signature used in the original code caused a mismatch and the runtime error.